# React navigation drawer V5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using react-navigation version 5.
I have tab navigation and drawer navigation together.

I'm trying to add an icon in my header to open/close drawer:

here is my custom right header for toggling the drawer:

```
const HeaderRight = ({ navigation }) => {   
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={ () =>{ navigation.toggleDrawer()}}>  //here is the problem
          <Image source={require('./assets/images/icons/drawer.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );}
```

this is my tab navigator:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function AppTab() {
  return (
     <Tab.Navigator>         
        <Tab.Screen name="Category" component={Category} />    
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
   );}
```

drawer navigator:

```
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();  
    function App() {
      return (    
          <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen name="AppTab" component={AppTab} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>  
      );}
```

and my stack navigator to theme mix all:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  export default function MyStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
    headerMode="screen"
     screenOptions={{
          headerRight: ({ navigation }) => (<HeaderRight navigation={navigation} />
        ),}} >
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

when I press the right header icon [image]

what I'm missing here?
the documents weren't really helpful

note:I have also try using dispatch but it didn't work:

> navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "randomcolor": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-woocommerce-api": "^1.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: does settings page contains the drawer? stack navigator should be the root navigator

Comment: no it doesn't .

Comment: what is ur navigation structure stack/drawer/tab?

Comment: I have a drawer navigator which one of the screens in the drawer is a tab navigator. I want to toggle drawer from header in each tab.

Comment: put drawer navigator in stack navigator

Comment: can you explain more?I have <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={App}/> and App is a drawer navigator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i have created an simple example deppending upon what i understood, i hope it helps,

u can use options props of Stack.Screen to render custom right or left button and in button component use useNavigation hook to get navigation prop and toggle the drawer user **navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer, useNavigation, DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createStackNavigator, HeaderBackButton, Header} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './src/home';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen component={Home} name="Home1" />
      <Tab.Screen component={Home} name="Home2" />
      {/*
       * Rest Screens
       */}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const DrawerComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen component={TabComponent} name="Main" />
      {/*
       * Rest Screens
       */}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

const HeaderLeft = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
        }}>
        <Text>Open</Text>
        {/* <Image source={require('./assets/images/icons/drawer.png')} /> */}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerLeft: ({}) => <HeaderLeft />
          }}
          component={DrawerComponent}
          name="Drawer"
        />
        {/*
         * Rest Screens
         */}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **toggleDrawer()** use **openDrawer()**

**STEPS**

```
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
```

If the above function not working try this:

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
```

**UPDATE CODE**

```
const HeaderRight = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
        }}
      >
        <Image source={require("./assets/images/icons/drawer.png")} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Make sure you have imported the package before using

Comment: I still get an error : TypeError : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.dispatch')

Comment: Add your package.json to this question

Comment: I've copied everything from your code but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try this -> this.props.navigation.openDrawer() instead of dispatch

Comment: I get this error : undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props')

Answer (score 0):

if `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` isnt work, you may try useNavigation.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

in your header `function()` add

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

and add `navigation.openDrawer()` to onPress

Answer (score 0):

this is worck for me !

```
        headerRight: () => (
          <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}> // this is a cutom button
    <Item
      title="Favorite"
      iconName="ios-menu"
      onPress={() => {navigation.navigation.toggleDrawer() }}
    />
  </HeaderButtons>
        ),
```